# Magento 2 make new method available in list.phtml

Tags: module, custom, magento2.2.2, list.phtml

If I need to create a method under `Magento\Catalog\Test\Block\Product\ListProduct`  Class

This class has methods such as:
`getProductItem`,`getProductNames`,`getProductsCount`,`getSortByValues`

I Would like to make `myOwnMethod` in my custom module without overwriting it the class `ListProduct` and use in:

`.../app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: You need to change that block class in the XML and then point to your custom block class which extends the `Magento\Catalog\Test\Block\Product\ListProduct` block class (if you want to keep functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably the only solution I've got welcome new one's please!

Create Block :`Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ListProduct.php`

in any Theme: `.../app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Call Block:

> $blockStore = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ListProduct');

Use your custom method from Block like so:

```
$blockStore->myOwnMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is create a class which extends `ListProduct`.
In your custom module's **Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ListProduct.php**

```
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\ListProduct {

    public function myOwnMethod() { … }

}
```

And then, you need to replace the references to that block in the layout. I believe the layout that uses this block is catalog_category_view, so in your module's **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" remove="true"/>
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list.extend" as="product_list" template="Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml">
            <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

Notice that this is nearly a perfect copy of the old **catalog_category_view.xml** but the previous block was removed, and replaced with a new block that has a different *class* and *template*

Comment: I don't want to remove the current `category.products.list`  or change `template="Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml"`  in my vendor all I want is to be able to have a method available to use in  any Theme  `list.phtml`  without having to add directly to` vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php` file.   Like appending a new Method onto `\Magento\Catalog\Block\ListProduct` ready to be used whenever is required.